# Android studio not recognizng a class?

Tags: java, android, class, android-studio

I'm trying to get some simple comms via WiFi between 2 devices & have been following [Sarthi Technology's tutorial.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7wEyV3jAIw4)

Unfortunatley I cant get Android Studio to recognize a class...

[image]

From the picture you can see that `WifiDirectBroadcastReceiver` is highlighted in red even though you can also see that it exists in the next tab.

The class declaration `public class WifiDirectBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver`

In MainActivity mReceiver is declared as so `BroadcastReceiver mReceiver;`

When I click the red lighht bulb it asks if I want to create the class & then complains that the class already exists!

I'm new to Java so what am I missing here? (btw the guy in the tutorial isnt having this issue)

**EDIT #1: Full code listings to provide a working example**

**MainActivity.java**

```
package qdivision.org.wifiexample2;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btnOnOff, btnDiscover, btnSend;
    ListView listView;
    TextView read_msg_box, connectionStatus;
    EditText writeMsg;

    WifiManager wifiManager;
    WifiP2pManager mManger;
    WifiP2pManager.Channel mChanel;

    BroadcastReceiver mReceiver;
    IntentFilter mIntentFilter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        initialWork();
        exqListener();
    }

    private void exqListener() {
        btnOnOff.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(wifiManager.isWifiEnabled()){
                    wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);
                    btnOnOff.setText("ON");
                }else{
                    wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
                    btnOnOff.setText("OFF");
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void initialWork() {

        btnOnOff = (Button) findViewById(R.id.onOff);
        btnDiscover = (Button) findViewById(R.id.discover);
        btnSend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendButton);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.peerListView);
        read_msg_box = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.readMsg);
        connectionStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.connectionStatus);
        writeMsg = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.writeMsg);

        wifiManager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

        mManger = (WifiP2pManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_P2P_SERVICE);
        mChanel = mManger.initialize(this, getMainLooper(), null);

        mReceiver = new WifiDirectBroadcastReceiver(mManger, mChanel, this);
        mIntentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        mIntentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION);
        mIntentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION);
        mIntentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION);
        mIntentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_THIS_DEVICE_CHANGED_ACTION);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        registerReceiver(mReceiver, mIntentFilter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
    }
}
```

**WifiDirectBroadcastReceiver.java**

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pManager;
import android.widget.Toast;

import qdivision.org.wifiexample2.MainActivity;

public class WifiDirectBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private WifiP2pManager mManager;
    private WifiP2pManager.Channel mChanel;
    private MainActivity mActivity;

    public WifiDirectBroadcastReceiver(WifiP2pManager mManager, WifiP2pManager.Channel mChanel, MainActivity mActivity)
    {
        this.mManager = mManager;
        this.mChanel = mChanel;
        this.mActivity = mActivity;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        String action = intent.getAction();

        if(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)){
            int state = intent.getIntExtra(WifiP2pManager.EXTRA_WIFI_STATE, -1);
            if(state == WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_ENABLED){
                Toast.makeText(context, "Wifi is ON", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Wifi is OFF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }else if(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)){
            //do something
        }else if(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)){
            //do something
        }else if(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_THIS_DEVICE_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)){
            //do something
        }
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/onOff"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="28dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
        android:text="Wifi On" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/discover"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/onOff"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/onOff"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="discover" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/peerListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/onOff"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/readMsg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/peerListView"
        android:layout_marginTop="31dp"
        android:text="Message"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="italic" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/writeMsg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/sendButton" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/sendButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:text="Send" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/connectionStatus"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="Connection Status"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="italic" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="qdivision.org.wifiexample2">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Progress update: I have tried all the recommendations to date but still the `WifiDirectBroadcastReceiver` class is not recognized by the `MainActivity`

**Solution:** the class had been saved in the wrong folder, once moved it all worked fine

Comment: Do you have an import at the top in red? Sometimes a bad import can block the quick action popup from importing the correct class. Otherwise, you will need to share your project structure and make sure that other class is properly part of the src.

Comment: Create an on-site MCVE - DO NOT rely on screenshots for that.

Comment: @Zoe I have no idea what that means

Comment: @DrBwts [mcve] - in your case, it means copy-paste the relevant code into the question too. Not as screenshots, text. You can use screenshots too, but they cannot be used instead of text.

Comment: OK thanks have included the code that is causing the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
BroadcastReceiver mReceiver;
```

to

```
WifiDirectBroadcastReceiver mReceiver;
```

Also check: 1) If import is correct 2) Try Clean -> Rebuild -> Invalidate cash and restart
Third way: from you class where you are calling it just press ALt+Enter and create class as Android Studio recommend it. So it will make all imports and connections properly

Comment: WifiDirectBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver, so in general this is not an issue.

Comment: @DrBwts updated answer. Basically the easiest way is third. Just make alt+enter as studio recommend create it and copy existing code. Thats the fastest way

Answer (score 1):

Check if the class you created is "public".

If it is, click on "Rebuild Project" or restart Android Studio, that will sometimes solve many problems.